# Identify if Visual Studio tests are being run manually or automatic

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, automated-tests

I am working on a C# project using Visual Studio 2022.  The project has a Unit Test assembly, and this works fine.  We can run tests in the Test Explorer and also the tests are run automatically in DevOps.

I would like to introduce a test into this assembly that needs some setup with an external utility app.  The external app will receive a message, modify it, and send it back to the source, but it needs to be run interactively.  It is a useful test to have in terms of product quality, but the tester needs to set up the environment so it can't be part of any automated test.

Is there any way to either:

- Specify that the test can only be run manually, and should not be part of an automated test run, or
- Detect whether the test is being run manually or automatically, so that it can just indicate success if run automatically?

Answer (score 0):

When using Xunit you can use the Trait attribute on your test to define a category and use this as filter when executing test in your pipeline.

So on a regular unit test you can add this:

```
[Trait("Category", "Unit")]
```

And on a more complex test you could add something like this:

```
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
```

And use this as filter in your pipeline. For example to only run unit tests:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "dotnet test ProjectWithTests.csproj"
    inputs:
      command: "test"
      projects: "ProjectWithTests.csproj"
      arguments: '--no-build --configuration "Release" --filter Category=Unit'
```

Comment: You can also tag the entire assembly if those tests are in a specific assembly. `[assembly: Category("Interactive")]`. This is NUnit though. Adjust accordingly.